# Protractor Angular 2 Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor

I'm getting the following error:

- Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined

This only happens when using angular specific selectors like "by.model". But selectors such as "by.css" work correctly . This is an Angular 2 app...

Test

```
it('should set focus', () => {
    //This works
    //var input = element(by.css('myclass'));
    //This fails
    var input = element(by.model('config.value'));
    input.clear();
    input.sendKeys('test');
    input.sendKeys(Key.TAB);
    input.click();
    var highlightedText = browser.executeScript(function getSelectionText()       
    {         
         return window.getSelection().toString(); 
    });
    expect(highlightedText).toEqual('test');
 });


exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5555',

  specs: [
    'dist/dev/**/*.e2e.js'
  ],
  exclude: [],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
  },
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: true}));

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  },

  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

chrome=49.0.2623.87
chromedriver=2.9.248315
platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64
node=5.9.1

Comment: Could you add your protractor.conf?

Comment: I updated the post with the config

Comment: What if you would add `browser.waitForAngular()` to `beforeEach` after the `browser.get()`?

Comment: browser.waitForAngular(); did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 54):

I found the answer on the angular.io site under developer docs.

[Upgrading from 1.x](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)

[image]

Right now angular selectors by.model and by.binding are not supported. Its not clear if these are features that are possible or that they are working on for angular 2.

Comment: ... few hours of my life were wasted because somebody was too lazy to not it in docs... https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html