# Protractor - unknown error: angular is not defined when using by.model

Tags: angular, unit-testing, webpack, protractor, end-to-end

I'm working on writing some protractor tests for my Angular component and keep getting an error "unknown error: angular is not defined" when I try to use by.model to select the input element.

Its odd because if I do this it works fine and pases:

```
it('should have an input element for searching', () => {
    var inputElement = element(by.model('searchText');
    expect(inputElement).toBeDefined();
});
```

But when I try to do something like this it fails with the angular undefined error:

```
it('should filter the search text', () => {
     var inputElement = element(by.model('searchText');
     expect(inputElement).toBeDefined();

     inputElement.clear()
     inputElement.click();
     inputElement.sendKeys('ICBC');

     var tableLengthRow = element.all(by.css('.animate-repeat').count();
     expect(tableLength).toBe(1);
});
```

If I replace this line:

```
var inputElement = element(by.model('searchText');
```

with this one:

```
var inputElement = element.all(by.tagName('input')).get(0);
```

and leave the rest as I have it the test passes.

Does anyone know why the first test above works with by.model but not the second one where I am actually clicking on the element?

And then how can I define angular on the page using Webpack and npm?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor Angular 2 Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201691/protractor-angular-2-failed-unknown-error-angular-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`by.model` is not supported in Angular (angular2, angular4 and on).

The recommended alternative is `by.css()`.

As per [angular/protractor's current readme](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.1.2#compatibility):

> Protractor works with AngularJS versions greater than 1.0.6/1.1.4, and is compatible with Angular applications. Note that **for Angular apps, the `by.binding()` and `by.model()` locators are not supported. We recommend using `by.css()`.**

Examples of the alternative at [Angular Guide - E2E Tests](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#e2e-tests):

```
Previous code               New code         Notes
by.model('$ctrl.query')     by.css('input')  The model matcher relies on AngularJS ng-model
by.model('$ctrl.orderProp') by.css('select') The model matcher relies on AngularJS ng-model
```

Comment: i don't understand, when can i use by.binding?

Comment: @FernandoGabrieli apparently, you can't, they are not supported in angular apps, says the readme quoted in the answer.

Comment: so that means we can not use by.model nor by.binding for angular 9 or angular 10 apps?

Comment: Apparently, yes. The [readme today says the `binding` and `model` are not supported and the recommended way is `by.css`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/c1e31e8d4cc6054fbf40ec2214d343377f07a050/README.md#compatibility).

Comment: thank you this was helpful for me :) and saved me a lot of time