# protractor - "angular is not defined" when using `browser.setLocation('/')`

Tags: angular, protractor, angular6, angular-e2e

Is it because `browser.setLocation` is not supported in angular v6 ([like `by.model` and `by.binding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201691/protractor-angular-2-failed-unknown-error-angular-is-not-defined))?

I have tried `await browser.waitForAngular()`, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I do wish to keep synchronization between angular/protractor (e.g. `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` and `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)`)

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that `browser.setLocation` is for angular v1 only, and I couldn't find an alternative for angular 2+.

I got it to work by executing a script to change the URL, and the angular router will do it without reloading the page (this is using `useHash` for the `RouterModule`):

```
const setLocation = url =>
  browser.executeScript(pUrl => window.location.href = `/#/${pUrl}`, url);
```

Then it works similarly to `browser.setLocation`:

```
 browser.get('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial');
 setLocation('api');
 expect(browser.getCurrentUrl())
   .toBe('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api');
```